# How to get second non null value per row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, analytics, data-analysis

How to get second non null value per row in pandas. I know that using first_valid_index() we can get first non null value per row but how to get second non null value.
Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`df.notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

Also , for handling cases where there can be no `NaN` values for a column use [`series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with the same solution but a condition which checks for the sum of null values

```
df.notna().cumsum().eq(2).idxmax().where(df.isna().sum().gt(1))
```

Example:

```
data = {'id': [np.nan,1,1,np.nan,2,3],
    'value': ['a','a',np.nan,np.nan,'b','c'],
    'obj_id': [np.nan,2,3,3,3,np.nan],
    'test': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame (data)
```

---

```
    id value  obj_id  test
0  NaN     a     NaN     1
1  1.0     a     2.0     2
2  1.0   NaN     3.0     3
3  NaN   NaN     3.0     4
4  2.0     b     3.0     5
5  3.0     c     NaN     6
```

---

For a column level check:

```
df.notna().cumsum().eq(2).idxmax().where(df.notna().sum().gt(1))

id        2
value     1
obj_id    2
test      1
dtype: float64
```

For rowlevel , you can use same logic but with axis=1:

```
df.notna().cumsum(1).eq(2).idxmax(1).where(df.notna().sum(1).gt(1))
0      test
1     value
2    obj_id
3      test
4     value
5     value
dtype: object
```